# Using httr + graph API for large files

Tags: r, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, httr

I'm trying to upload large files to SharePoint Online directly through R using the Microsoft Graph API. To this end, I'm using the API's `createUploadSession`, documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0).

My code looks like this:

```
httr::PUT(url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/.../createUploadSession", 
          headers   = add_headers(.headers = headers), 
          body      = httr::upload_file(file),
          encode    = mime::guess_type(file), 
          verbose())
```

(where 'headers' include authentication and host name, here `graph.microsoft.com`)

And the resultant request looks like this:

```
-> PUT /v1.0/sites/.../createUploadSession HTTP/1.1
-> Host: graph.microsoft.com
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.2
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: text/plain
-> Content-Length: 4543954542
```

Of course, this fails:

```
<- HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
<- Content-Type: text/html
<- Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
<- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
<- Date: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 12:32:29 GMT
<- Connection: close
<- Content-Length: 67
<-
```

since as the documentation says, we need to upload in 327,680 byte chunks. However, I was under the assumption that `httr`'s `upload_file` allows for streaming. This is where I'm stuck: it looks like my request is still trying to upload this all at once, so how do I 'invoke' this streaming behavior? And is some kind of `while` loop required to continue sending the next chunk of data?

Comment: In case if you're Sharepoint and want to upload bigger file sizes then you may want to give a try using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-large-files-by-using-rest

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I am!

Comment: Have you considered the option that i provided above? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is now available in the [Microsoft365R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/index.html) package. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this package.

```r
site <- get_sharepoint_site("sitename")
site$get_drive()$upload_file("path/to/file", "destfilename")
```

Comment: I've seen this package! Very nice work. The only issue is that it requires admin intervention (as you have detailed in your vignettes - I've tried everything). I have been using a personal package that skirts this (https://github.com/KaiAragaki/sharepointr) but I have not implemented large file handling. I would love to use your package instead, but this will have to do for now. Thanks again!

Comment: `AzureGraph::create_graph_login` uses the Azure CLI app ID by default, which is one of the workarounds mentioned in the Microsoft365R auth vignette. So there's nothing stopping you using the latter package